# Docker for HOME directory for nltk?

Tags: python-2.7, nltk, docker

I need to include `nltk` library that is supposed to be read from `$HOME/nltk_data`

In local machine, I just run

`python -m nltk.downloader -d $HOME/nltk_data all`

But I have no idea how to get this to work in `Dockerfile`

`RUN python -m nltk.downloader -d $HOME/nltk_data all`

would work?

How do I set up `$HOME` in docker container?

I am seeing these messages

```
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package abc to //nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/abc.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package alpino to //nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/alpino.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package biocreative_ppi to //nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/biocreative_ppi.zip.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your own and set your $HOME env variable. Here is how:

```
RUN mkdir /user
ENV HOME /user
WORKSPACE /user
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a test:

```
docker run -i -t ubuntu bash
echo $HOME
root@7fe16f3e86bc:/# echo $HOME
/
```

The home directory for the root user is set too `/` so your should be able to run:

```
RUN python -m nltk.downloader -d /nltk_data all
```

Alternatively your can also use the USER command as shown below to set the default user for all subsequent commands. This will mean the the $HOME for all subsequent command maps to /home/bob

```
RUN useradd --user-group --system --home-dir /home/bob bob
USER bob
RUN python -m nltk.downloader -d $HOME/nltk_data all
```